# using javascript libraries don't work on webpage when loading data from json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I created a javascript code to create grid and populate it with cards, using data from json file, and load them into a web page.
This is the code:

```
// load data into grid container
const container = document.querySelector(".grid");

// get data from the file, using loadData(), inside it populateContainer
function loadData() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("get", "data.json");
  request.onload = () => {
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      populateContainer(json);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn("error");
    }
  };

  request.send();
}

function populateContainer(json) {
  while (container.firstChild) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
  }

  json.forEach((row) => {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.setAttribute("class", `grid-item ${row[7]}`);
    card.setAttribute("data-category", `${row[7]}`);

    // header
    let header = document.createElement("div");
    header.setAttribute("class", "card-header");
    header.innerHTML = `Current = ${row[1]}$ Original Price = ${row[2]}$ / Discount = ${row[3]}%`;
    card.appendChild(header);

    // pic
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("class", "card-image");
    img.src = `https://${row[6]}`;
    card.appendChild(img);

    // BODY
    let cardBody = document.createElement("div");
    cardBody.setAttribute("class", "card-content");
    card.appendChild(cardBody);

    // -->Title + link
    let cardTitle = document.createElement("h4");
    cardTitle.setAttribute("class", "card-title");
    cardTitle.innerHTML = `<a href='https://${row[4]}'>${row[0]}</a>`;
    cardBody.appendChild(cardTitle);

    container.appendChild(card);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  loadData();
});
```

This is the html body (the javascript script is in `main.js` file):

```
<body>
    
        <div id="filters" class=".filter-button-group button-group">
            <div class="button All"><a href="#">show all</a></div>
            <div class="button HomeGarden"><a href="#">Home & Garden</a></div>
            <div class="button Electronics"><a href="#">Electronics</a></div>
            <div class="button MomKids"><a href="#">Mom & Kids</a></div>
            <div class="button SportsOutdoor"><a href="#">Sports & Outdoor</a></div>
            <div class="button Accessories"><a href="#">Accessories</a></div>
            <div class="button HealthBeauty"><a href="#">Health & Beauty</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid">            
        </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

The code work well, and it create the grid and elements inside it,
but when I want to add a filter for those cards by category, using library like `https://listjs.com` or `https://isotope.metafizzy.co` it doesnt work.

How I can apply the filter to my code ?

Comment: what kind of filter? sry i dont follow

Answer (score 0):

What issues exactly did occur when trying to filter?
Here is a [technical cut-through](https://plnkr.co/edit/QafM66ancxTORirH) on how to get your script working by the following steps:

- Include [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co) (as a `script`-tag,using the download-link)
- Add "data-filter" attributes in HTML (I added three of them as an example):

```html
    <div class="button Electronics" data-filter="[data-category='Electronics']">
```

- Initialize Isotope:

```js
    $grid = new Isotope( '.grid',{
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    });
```

- Whenever you want to filter, filter. I bound your links to the .arrange-fn using JQuery, but feel free to do it some other way:

```js
    $('#filters').on( 'click', 'div.button', function() {
      var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
      $grid.arrange({ filter: filterValue });
    });
```

Did you get any issues trying to do so? I mocked your JSON since I got no service returning it, but in case it's a timing issue, just put the initialization (see above) right below the `container.appendChild(card);`, that should make it work.

Feel free to ask if I didn't cover some aspect of your question.

Best wishes

Comment: this is the website folder please check, https://github.com/maxscender/001deal.git

Comment: Well, I don't see any click-event listener in you code (see bulletpoint `Whenever you want to filter,...` above. Additionally, you simply inserted my first snipplet in there - think about where it should go correctly. You just pasted it in there and it has neither a label in it nor a closing tag. Inspect [my plunkr linked above](https://plnkr.co/edit/QafM66ancxTORirH?preview) to see details.